# Importing Git repo from Azure DevOps into RedHat JBPM

Tags: azure-devops, jbpm, git-clone

There are many posts on the URLs used to access repositories in Azure DevOps but mine has an additional wrinkle: I am cloning from a Azure Devops git repo into a JBPM Business Central repository under RedHat EAP 7.3 using Https . JBPM's Business Central has textboxes for URL, username and password.

My understanding is that one should use a Personal Access Token (herein PAT) for accessing Azure DevOps repositories (I have tried many times without using a PAT).  Microsoft posts show a few ways to reference repositories as URLs.  When I use a URL of

{PAT}@{server}.visualstudio.com:/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}

The connection timeouts on its "connect" method after about 30 seconds

```
Caused by: org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.commands.Clone$CloneException: Error cloning origin <{PAT}@{server}.visualstudio.com:/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository}>.
         ... 101 more
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: {PAT}@{server}.visualstudio.com:/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository} : Connection timed out: connect
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:181)
        ... 104 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
...
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:137)
        ... 111 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
...
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
        ... 113 more
```

and with

{PAT}@{server}:/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository} I almost immediately get

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: {PAT}@{server}:/{org}/{project}/_git/{repository} : remote hung up unexpectedly
...
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:243)
... 104 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.(String.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProviderUserInfo.promptPassword(CredentialsProviderUserInfo.java:121)
at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPassword.start(UserAuthPassword.java:57)
```

Putting my username and password in their corresponding blocks does not help (and which PAT already covers).  Any thoughts on the correct URL to use?  And, out of curiosity, why is git on Azure DevOps seemingly tied to their Visual Studio server?

Comment: You can try to use the url from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfUch.png) and try to use pat as password. Or try this format: `https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repo-name}`.  Here is a [document](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1281493) you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks.  A URL like the above produces the long-delayed connection error like I mentioned above with respect to Visual Studio.  The document is from version 6 (and they are on major version 7).  Trying to work with that to chain to other documents to try to get to a solution - thanks again!

Comment: In reading more about Azure DevOps I see that it is the latest in a line of Microsoft Products descending from TFS.  I cannot pull code from the Azure Devops repo into Eclipse without first going to the command line (ie command line git works, but eGit, Team Explorer Everywhere - TEE - seemingly don't). Is TFS a protocol, as well as a product - ie the protocol could be causing issues?  TEE looks like it should use HTTPS with my PAT, so JBOSS should be able to consume the HTTPS if TFS uses standards